# Cosine of the Natural Logarithm - Series Expansion

Tags: logarithms, trigonometric-series

I am interested in a computable series expansion of the following equation:

$f(n) = \cos(\log(n))$

Specifically, I am interested in real values of $n$ where $n>1$.

From basic series definitions of the two functions you have:

$\cos(x) = \sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{m}x^{2m}}{(2m)!}$

$\log(n) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k}(\frac{n-1}{n})^k$

Can these two representations be defined in terms of one recursive relationship as follows:

$f(n) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{g(n, k)}$

There seems to be a lot of information about logarithmic cosine functions but not the other way around for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=series%20expansion%20of%20cos%28log%20x%29%20around%201),
$$
\cos\log x = \sum_{n\geq0} \frac{1}{2} (-1+x)^n \left(\binom{-i}{n}+\binom{i}{n}\right).
$$
Its radius of convergence is only 1, though. I believe that the $i$ in the above expression is $\sqrt{-1}$, and the binomial coefficient is defined using the $\Gamma$ function. So I'm not sure this expression is very helpful. If you only want the first few terms that you can ask alpha.

Comment: No, in the question I specify that I am interested in values of x > 1.  According to alpha that series only converges for |1-x| < 1.

Comment: Look again. The radius of convergence around 1 is 1. According to alpha it converges for $|x-1|<1$.

Comment: So what about x > 10?  I have a series expression of cos(log(x)) where x are positive integers.  Also, I'm hoping to find something that is computable.  Expressions with i, are not directly computable, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Wait for other answers, I guess.